# Accessing the files of the Plug and Play android device via WIN API

Tags: android, winapi, windows-services, mtp, plug-and-play

Let me keep my explanation simple. I am writing a simple windows service, to detect android devices connected to the computer via USB and access the device's memory to read camera photos.

Using `RegisterDeviceNotification()` in the WIN API we can get registered to get notified for any device change (Devices added/removed from the computer). In my case I register to get notified when the USB devices are connected to the computer.
So when a volume device is connected we can get the drive letter using `dbcv_unitmask` from the `PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME` structure. This works absolutely well for a USB drive. I can then access my USB drive because of the known drive letter.

But, in my case the android device connects using MTP protocol and windows does recognize a new USB device being attached but does not seem to assign a drive letter to it. So, now I have no way to access the memory of the device programmatically.

Please let me know if there is a way to access the android PNP device via WIN API.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need a drive letter to access a volume. The drive letter is there for reasons of compatibility with DOS. There are other ways to identify and access a volume (see [Naming a Volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365248.aspx)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the alternative was to use WPD (Windows portable device API ) to access the mtp device.